# Not sure why the data object is not passing through to the display function?

Tags: javascript

So I have an object that contains information that has the ID, input value for a new task, date, and time.

The HTML element is for user input and to show where I am getting the information from.

HTML

```
 <div class="form">
        <input class ="user-input" type="text">
        <input class="date" type="date">
        <input class="time" type="time">
        <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
 </div>
```

JS

```
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

function makeNewTask() {

  const data = {

    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };

  return data
  
}
//function that creates new tasks with date and time
function display(data) {
  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  tasks.innerHTML = `
       <div class="task-content">
        <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
        <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="action-buttons">
        <button onclick="editItem()" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
        <button onclick="deleteItem()" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
        <button onclick="completeItem()" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(data);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  makeNewTask();
}

// this function is the add the task 
function addTask() {
  display();
}
```

The End goal is to figure out why the data object is not being passed into the new function when I returned the data in the `makeNewTask()` and add the callback function of `makeNewTask()` to `display(data)`

I have also added a picture of the error I am getting, and by that error, the data object is not being passed through to the display function where you can see the ```data.id`` etc. that is where the information is meant to go and print on the screen. when the user clicks on the add task button

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your display function was having empty parameter inside addTask() function and createID() was not defined. so I modified it to fix the issue as follows:

1. Added createID() function, taskList and currentId vars.
2. Explicitely call makeNewTask() inside display() and remove existing declaration ot the makeNewTask() function from bottom.
3. Added div to view the tasks

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
  <input class="user-input" type="text" />
  <input class="date" type="date" />
  <input class="time" type="time" />
  <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
</div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

JS:

```
  var taskList = [];
  var currentID = 0;
  function createId() {
    currentID++;
    return currentID;
  }
  const el = {
    form: document.querySelector(".form"),
    input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
    list: document.querySelector(".list"),
    date: document.querySelector(".date"),
    time: document.querySelector(".time"),
  };

  function makeNewTask() {
    const data = {
      id: createId(),
      taskNew: el.input.value,
      taskDate: el.date.value,
      taskTime: el.time.value,
    };

    return data;
  }
  //function that creates new tasks with date and time
  function display() {
    const tasks = document.createElement("div");
    data = makeNewTask();
    tasks.innerHTML = `
   <div class="task-content">
    <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
    <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
    <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
    <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
  </div>

  <div class="action-buttons">
    <button onclick="editItem()" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
    <button onclick="deleteItem()" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
    <button onclick="completeItem()" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
 </div>
 </div>`;

    taskList.push(data);
    el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  }

  // this function is the add the task
  function addTask() {
    display();
  }
```

Now, addTask() should work. Hope that helps!